# How to react to a girl's mum inviting themselves to my daughter's party?

Tags: pre-schooler, communication, birthday, party, etiquette

I'm having a 4th birthday party for my daughter, and invited about 8 girls out of 40 or so kids from her Kindergarden class.

Today I received a text from a girl's mum, saying that they lost the invitation and can she [RSVP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSVP) with me.  Problem is that her daughter was not invited in the first place, and they must have found out from someone else, and think that it's a 'whole class party'. My daughter doesn't want her daughter to be there as they do not really play together.

Do we just invite them to make this whole thing go away, or stand our ground and let them know that they were not invited? If so, how to put it gently?

Comment: Thank you everyone for their 2 cents worth.  It took a lot of convincing (to my daughter) that we should include this girl at her party.  She asked a lot of why's, and I explained that sometimes you have to include people to not make them feel sad.  My son gave an example of his inviting everyone even though he didnt want a couple of the boys who he never played with.  Besides, friendship dynamics will change in the next few years, so you never know...  My daughter prefers few and intimate friendships but perhaps this is a good way to get her to step out of her comfort zone.  Thanks again

Comment: Please do me a favor and follow up on this her after a couple of months. It looks like that mother is a bit too intrusive, and giving in as you did could backfire. Some people don't stop if you don't say NO very clearly. I would have said no, and I wonder how your way of handling it works out.

Answer (score 11):

Just tell her simply:

> We have planned to have a small party with my daughter's close friends, and so we did not invite the whole class.

Where to take it from there is up to you. If this girl and your daughter truly don't play together, the other mother should be reasonable enough to understand that her daughter is not a close friend. There may also be a cultural element here. Is it common for parents to bring treats to class for their child's birthday? If you plan to do so, you can add:

> Your daughter is of course welcome to join the rest of the class in celebrating my daughter's birthday at school.

That together with the above should make it clear that they are not invited to your daughter's personal birthday party, but if you don't have the second bit then you may wish to add one more statement to make it perfectly clear:

> Your daughter was not invited because of the limited number of guests we're comfortable accommodating.

You should feel no obligation to invite anyone to a party which you host.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I think she is of the believe that the girls are better friends than they actually are, so to explicitly say that her daughter is not a close friend will definitely hurt some feelings. The party is at a venue so it's hard to use space as an excuse. I am worried this will turn into awkward moments at drop off and pick ups for the rest of the year (and possibly next year), hence really considering inviting her just to make life easier. I feel like such a wuss. We are actually bringing in cupcakes to kinder tomorrow to celebrate. The joy of modern kids' party politics!

Comment: @NosyLadyBug It is difficult, and with the above method you may still make her feel hurt, but I feel like it is the gentlest approach that still clearly communicates your needs without possibly opening up the door to anyone in the class who wants to barge in.

Comment: Perhaps change "close friends" to "few closest friends"?

Comment: @DanHenderson not a bad idea

Comment: Why should one more kid make a difference?

Comment: @RachelS It's a class of 40 kids. If you don't draw the line somewhere you may end up with more--if not this time, the next.

Comment: I don't agree that drawing the line and setting it in stone is necessary.  Three things can happen.  You don't draw lines, in which case, yes, you will get everyone and their cousin.  You draw lines and set them in stone, which I find, in individual oriented cultures, often leads to cliquish behavior and hurt feelings.  Or you draw the line but be willing to flex here and there to demonstrate kindness and grace.  You may get one, or even a few more (not all 40, I am sure), but the value of instilling a spirit of welcoming grace in your kids is definitely worth that.

Comment: You can't be everyone's best friend, NosyLadyBug.  If your daughter does not have a close relationship, or much interaction with this other child, then fall-out or awkwardness should be minimal, right?  Why would there be uncomfortable moments if they don't really interact? If the child is someone who is a bit of an outsider and is treated poorly by kids because of general childish cliquishness, then I'd consider expanding the guest list just to keep my child from falling into that mindset.  Otherwise, if your event is set up with the best intentions, you shouldn't be guilted into changing.

Comment: @NosyLadyBug: It's not telling the mother that the children are not best friends that hurts her feeling, its the fact that they are not best friends.

Comment: @RachelS: One more kid makes a difference between eight friends that were invited, and eight friends that were invited plus one girl whose mother invited herself.

Answer (score 0):

I would encourage you to welcome this kid into the party.  By doing so, you could teach your child the value of being inclusive even towards people we do not hit it off with.  This other child might be feeling left out and might have even told her parent that she was invited.  Or the parent might be feeling like her child is being left out and trying to look out for her by putting you in a position that is a little awkward, but that gives you the chance to extend grace.

I come from a culture that tends to be very inclusive, very group oriented.  Inviting several people out of a group, means inviting the whole group, and you just better be prepared.  But I have lived most of my life in the US, where the expectation is that you only go to a party if you are explicitly invited.

I find that the group oriented culture, in this factor, has a lot of positive value. I have used that to teach my children to be kind and welcoming even to kids that they would not normally gravitate towards.

You have a great chance here to teach your child grace and kindness to someone that may be feeling left out.  I suggest you take it.  A word of caution, if you do choose to extend this grace to the other child, the truly gracious thing to do is to not say a word about it to either the other child's parent or the other child.  And you will need to make sure your child understands that.

Comment: I like the idea of showing her child how to act with grace and kindness to others but it would be wise to get more details from her child as to why she doesn't want the un-invited classmate at her party. Her child may not know it's good to make others feel welcome or there may be a stronger reason for excluding someone.

Comment: I don't see any value in obligation to invite people you may not go along well with. For what reason? Because they are part of the group that has been created randomly (school class)? Sorry but no. If it would be a small group that I belong to, then maybe.

Comment: I'd see that as extremely disrespectful to the wishes of the daughter. She invited eight friends. That's what she wanted. She didn't invite nine people. She didn't invite the girl whose mother is trying to invite herself. That girl might be number 9 on her list of friends, or number 17, or number 40 out of a class of 40 and be the one person who she definitely doesn't want to be there.

Comment: Reading the original post carefully, it looks like the uninvited girls mother is lying - she says she lost the invitation when her daughter wasn't invited at all. If that mother had said "my daughter feels left out, would you mind if she comes and joins the party", that would be a different thing.

Comment: Thanks guys.  Really appreciate everyone input.  We have always invited everyone with my older son, as he's got that 'plays with everyone' personality.  My daughter is the opposite and prefers a few close friends.  We have pictures of everyone from her whole class, and we have spend the last 2 months asking her who she will invite.  Definitely not that girl.  Anyway, we have now decided to invite her, as I cannot bear hurting the feelings of this girl, who is an only child.

Comment: @NosyLadyBug I would say that you should either stick with your original plan and let the uninvited person know that they are not invited, or if you are going to change your mind, you should invite everyone as you have done with your son. Just inviting this one extra child will confuse the issue in your daughter's mind, and could have unforeseen consequences if other children start asking why they didn't get an invitation.

Comment: @PhilipNgai - good comment.  Yes, good to check further why the little girl would not want this class-mate at her party.  One of my kids was the victim of bullying for a little while, and I'd totally support her in not wanting to invite that kid over.

Comment: @gnasher729 - "the uninvited girls mother is lying".  You have no basis for jumping to such a conclusion.  Even if you try to soften it with "looks like", it is still offensive.  The mother said "they lost the invitation".  It is totally possible the little girl thought the invitations had been put on each kids' desk at school and she had lost hers, and told mom she had lost it at school.  It is judgmental to even imply lying with so little to go on.

Comment: NosyLadyBug.  Kudos on the decision to invite the girl.  When you say "cannot bear hurting the feelings of this girl", you demonstrate kindness that goes beyond obligation.  That is the very definition of grace - undeserved favor.  This will not be lost on your daughter.

Comment: @AgapwIesu: I was taught to tell the truth. The whole mess comes from the fact that NosyLadyBug didn't tell the truth, which was "you were not invited". And in your answer you encourage her again to keep the truth away from people, and worse yet to convince her daughter to not say the truth. Being unable to be honest is the one thing that causes most trouble in life, because truth has that ugly habit of coming out eventually. What do you suggest should NosyLadyBug tell other mothers, if they ask why their daughter wasn't invited? Because they didn't lose their invitation?

Comment: @gnasher729: I was taught to "tell the truth in love."  Which sometimes means one bites ones tongue and does not say something that while truthful may be hurtful.  When you meet a guy weighing 400lbs, you don't say "Hi, my name is Gnasher, and you are fat."  Just because it is true, does not mean it **has** to be said.  Sometimes kindness and grace is the higher value and does not make one "unable to be honest."  You are talking as if honesty is the ultimate value and has to be done without discretion.  If the other mom were to ask, at this point, if her daughter was invited, I would encourage

Comment: @gnasher729 NosyLadyBug to say, "actually not, we couldn't invite everyone in the class, so we had limited ourselves to a few people, but that is ok, i am inviting you now and we'll be happy to have you."  If some other mom asked after the fact why they were not invited, I would say, be honest, say "we were limiting the number because we could not handle the whole class."  But none of this means that one has to volunteer facts that while true, may be hurtful.  Honesty, yes, discretion and kindness, **also yes**.

Comment: Prepare for a 40-children party then! If your group-oriented culture is so great, why is it that is you going to live in America, rather than Americans massively migrating to your country?

Comment: @David People migrate to the U.S. because it has many things about its culture that are better - more adherence to law and order, better financial opportunities, etc.  But to pretend that this means that the U.S. has nothing to learn from other cultures is ethnocentric ignorance.  All cultures have good and bad values, some more good than others, but all have at least some good we can learn from.  I have lived in several different countries in my life, and I consider myself the richer for being willing to learn from each culture.